# Parametric equation in sin/cos having solutions whose difference is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Consider the equation $$m\cdot\cos x-(m+1)\cdot\sin x=m$$ where $m$ is a real parameter. I need to find the value(s) of $m$ for which this equation admits two solutions whose difference is $\frac{\pi}{2} $. What I have tried so far : I set $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ and $\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}$ are solutions of the equation. I plugged in both and obtained $\cos\alpha+(2m+1)\cdot\sin\alpha=0$. But I don’t know where to go from here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am a little confused. If you find a solution $x$ then you know that $x + 2n\pi$ is a solution for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. So you will have an infinite number of solutions. Are you saying that among these "infinite solutions", there are only two and when taking the difference between the principal ones, they have a difference of $\pi/2$?

Comment: Show how you get $\cos\alpha+(2m+1)\sin\alpha=0$, please.